# Splitting an address string in SQL

Tags: split, substring, case, patindex

I have a table called CUSTTABLE on an sql server database that has a column containing addresses. In the Netherlands the street name always comes before the house number and then the apartment information if it's an apartment. I want to separate the street name, the number information into two strings. The data looks like this:

```
CUSTTABLE
Kerkstraat 1
Kleine Kerkstraat 5B
Kerstraat 118B/A5
```

Thus, some street names have more than 1 word, and some adresses have apartment information and some don't. Some house numbers have non-numeric characters as well. I want it to be:

```
Street_name           House_number
Kerksstraat           1
Kleine Kerkstraat     5B
Kerkstraat            118B/A5
```

I'm able to extra the Street name and House number using the following code. I'm receiving an error when there is a 'NULL' entry in the database when I'm using the following code.

```
LEFT(STREET,PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',STREET)-1)'Street name',
SUBSTRING(STREET,PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',STREET)+1,PATINDEX('%, %',STREET+ ', ')-PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',STREET)-1)'House number',
```